# Comparing 2 columns of two Python Pandas dataframes and getting the common rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframe as follows:

```
DF1=
    A    B   C    D
0   AA   BA  KK   0
1   AD   BD  LL   0
2   AF   BF  MM   0

DF2=
    K    L
0   AA   BA
1   AD   BF
2   AF   BF
```

At the end what I want to get is:

```
DF1=
    A    B   C    D
0   AA   BA  KK   1
1   AD   BD  LL   0
2   AF   BF  MM   1
```

So, I want to compare two dataframe, I want to see which rows of first data frame (for column A and B) are in common of of second dataframe(Column K and L) and assign 1 on the coulmn D of first dataframe.

I can use for loop, but It will be very slow for large number of entries.

Any clue or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":['AA','AD','AD'], "B":['BA','BD','BF']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":['AA','AD'], 'B':['BA','BF']})
df1['compressed']=df1.apply(lambda x:'%s%s' % (x['A'],x['B']),axis=1)
df2['compressed']=df2.apply(lambda x:'%s%s' % (x['A'],x['B']),axis=1)
df1['Success'] = df1['compressed'].isin(df2['compressed']).astype(int)
print df1

    A   B     compressed   Success
0  AA  BA      AABA          1
1  AD  BD      ADBD          0
2  AD  BF      ADBF          1
```

Comment: How is your answer related to the original question?

Comment: I have tried with different dataframe, it serves the purpose.

Comment: but your desired output is not what the original question was about you should update your question or post a new question

Comment: this is a confusing response and doesn't explain what is happening or why.  also there is at least one other, better, answer on this page.

Answer (score 17):

This would be easier if you renamed the columns of `df2` and then you can compare row-wise:

```
In [35]:

df2.columns = ['A', 'B']
df2
Out[35]:
    A   B
0  AA  BA
1  AD  BF
2  AF  BF
In [38]:

df1['D'] = (df1[['A', 'B']] == df2).all(axis=1).astype(int)
df1
Out[38]:
    A   B   C  D
0  AA  BA  KK  1
1  AD  BD  LL  0
2  AF  BF  MM  1
```

Comment: And if you can't rename them, you can create a new `DataFrame` dynamically whose contents are a view on `df2` but whose column names match `df1`'s, and then it's just this code again.

Comment: You could just assign the result of `rename` to another df and compare that too so `df3 = df2.rename(columns={'K':'A', 'L':'B'})`

Comment: Or just use `df2.rename(…)` directly in the expression instead of storing it in a temporary name `df3`.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that your answer is still basically the right answer even if he _doesn't_ make it easy for himself (and it's still not that hard to use), so hopefully he'll accept this answer even if he for some reason can't change the definition of `df2`.

Comment: @Alexander this is what abarnert stated in his 2nd comment above, it depends on what the background on all this is

Comment: What if, DF1 have more or less no of rows than DF2?

Comment: You'd have to merge in that case to find the common rows and then do some kind of diff between the merged and df2 but it depends on the order and how they differ as it becomes complicated depending on how they differ

Answer (score 6):

```py
df1['ColumnName'].isin(df2['ColumnName']).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DF1.merge(right=DF2, left_on=[DF1.A, DF1.B], right_on=[DF2.K, DF2.L], indicator=True, how='left')
```

gives:

```
A   B   C  D    K    L     _merge
0  AA  BA  KK  0   AA   BA       both
1  AD  BD  LL  0  NaN  NaN  left_only
2  AF  BF  MM  0   AF   BF       both
```

So, as above, indicator does the job.