# Flag similarities between dataframes in new column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I would like to compare two pandas DataFrames of different length and identify matching index numbers. When values match I would like to flag those values in a new column.

```
df1:
Index    Column 1
41660    Apple
41935    Banana
42100    Strawberry
42599    Pineapple

df2:
Index    Column 1
42599    Pineapple

Output:
Index    Column 1    'Matching Index?'
41660    Apple
41935    Banana
42100    Strawberry
42599    Pineapple   True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing 2 columns of two Python Pandas dataframes and getting the common rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291032/comparing-2-columns-of-two-python-pandas-dataframes-and-getting-the-common-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are really the index then you can use `intersection` on the indices:

```
In [61]:
df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index), 'flag'] = True
df1

Out[61]:
         Column 1  flag
Index                  
41660       Apple   NaN
41935      Banana   NaN
42100  Strawberry   NaN
42599   Pineapple  True
```

Otherwise use `isin`:

```
In [63]:
df1.loc[df1['Index'].isin(df2['Index']), 'flag'] = True
df1

Out[63]:
   Index    Column 1  flag
0  41660       Apple   NaN
1  41935      Banana   NaN
2  42100  Strawberry   NaN
3  42599   Pineapple  True
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @EdChum's answer. If you can live with a different value than `True` in your matching column try:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator='Flag')
   Index      Column       Flag
0  41660       Apple  left_only
1  41935      Banana  left_only
2  42100  Strawberry  left_only
3  42599   Pineapple       both
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the isin()-method:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [41660,  'Apple'],
    [41935,  'Banana'],
    [42100,  'Strawberry'],
    [42599,  'Pineapple'],
                         ]
                   , columns=['Index', 'Column 1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [42599,  'Pineapple'],
                         ]
                   , columns=['Index', 'Column 1'])

df1['Matching'] = df1['Index'].isin(df2['Index'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   Index    Column 1 Matching
0  41660       Apple    False
1  41935      Banana    False
2  42100  Strawberry    False
3  42599   Pineapple     True
```