# Return rows where values of one column matches with other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df which has multiple columns, where two of the columns are 'Name1' and 'Name2'. I want to return the rows where Name1 is same as Name2. I tried doing this -

```
Result=df[df.Name1 == df.Name2]
```

This is what I have

```
df=
Name1    Class   Section    Name2
AA       BA      KK         AA
AD       BD      LL         DA
AF       BF      MM         AF
```

This is what I want -

```
Result=
Name1    Class   Section    Name2
AA       BA      KK         AA
AF       BF      MM         AF
```

It doesn't seem to return me all the rows. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should use join/merge and create new dataframe.

Comment: This should also help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291032/comparing-2-columns-of-two-python-pandas-dataframes-and-getting-the-common-rows

Comment: could you add some sample output

Comment: @rgalbo Added sample input and output

Comment: are all of the strings stripped or homogeneous? make sure they are all same case and stripped

Comment: @rgalbo Yes they are all stripped and are homogeneous. Casing is same.

Comment: try `Result=df[df.Name1.str.strip() == df.Name2.str.strip()]`  this will get rid of white space before and after.  If this works, then you had spaces messing with you.

Comment: Could you show us the rows that the code didn't pick up?