# Compare two columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe: df1, df2

```
name     gender
John      1
David     1 
Lilly     0
Young     0
Lisa      0
Wang      1

 name     gender
 Andy      1
 Lilly     1 
 Wang     0
 Mina    0
 John     0
 Claire      1
```

The two dataframes are both name-gender pair. I am trying to detect same names but assigned different gender in both dataframe(e.g., Lilly in df1 is assigned 0 and in df2 is assigned 1). I want to print a dataframe only shows that.

I used code

```
df2[df2[df1['name'] == df2['name'] and df2['gender'] != df1['gender']]
```

This code doesn't return an error but kept running forever. I wonder what did I do wrong. Is there any pandas command that can solve this?

Comment: [Comparing 2 columns of two Python Pandas dataframes and getting the common rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291032/comparing-2-columns-of-two-python-pandas-dataframes-and-getting-the-common-rows)

Answer (score 0):

`merge` filter then `drop`

```
df2.merge(df1,on='name',suffixes=('','d')).query('gender!=genderd').drop('genderd',1)
   name  gender
0  Lilly       1
1   Wang       0
2   John       0
```