# Get a specific row value by comparasion of two dataFrames with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparator

==============

### I have a firts DataFrame **df1** who looks like something like this:

| Name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Paris |
| Bob | Berlin |
| Alice | Paris |
| Alice | Miami |
| Toto | NYC |
| Bob | NYC |
| Mark | Berlin |
| Joe | Paris |
| ... | ... |

### Then i have a second DataFrame **df2** who looks like this too :

| Name | Location | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Paris | 0.3 |
| Bob | Paris | 0.2 |
| Bob | Berlin | 0.4 |
| Alice | Miami | 0.1 |
| Lucas | NYC | 0.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to make a function `searchedValue()` who implements each rows of my `df1` in a new column `["SEARCHEDVALUE"]` with the corresponding  `df2["VALUE"]` with these two conditions :

By checking if `df1["NAME"]` is in `df2` `and` if `df1["LOCATION"]` is in my `df2`, then return the `df2` VALUE corresponding to the matching row... else return no match found

I know that i can use something like this to implement my columns with my function:

```
df1["SearchedValue"] = df2.apply(searchedValue)
```

But i haven't find solution to build my function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing 2 columns of two Python Pandas dataframes and getting the common rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291032/comparing-2-columns-of-two-python-pandas-dataframes-and-getting-the-common-rows)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess not, the folowing post return the boolean value of the comparaison but not the specific value of the matching comparaison. I want to get de  `df2 VALUE` if `df1 NAME = df2 NAME & df1 LOCATION = df2 LOCATION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Bob', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Alice', 3: 'Alice', 4: 'Toto'},
 'Location': {0: 'Paris', 1: 'Berlin', 2: 'Paris', 3: 'Miami', 4: 'NYC'}})
```

df:

```
    Name Location
0    Bob    Paris
1    Bob   Berlin
2  Alice    Paris
3  Alice    Miami
4   Toto      NYC
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Bob', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Alice', 3: 'Alice', 4: 'Lucas'},
 'Location': {0: 'Paris', 1: 'Berlin', 2: 'Paris', 3: 'Miami', 4: 'NYC'},
 'Value': {0: 0.3, 1: 0.2, 2: 0.4, 3: 0.1, 4: 0.0}})
```

df2:

```
    Name Location  Value
0    Bob    Paris    0.3
1    Bob   Berlin    0.2
2  Alice    Paris    0.4
3  Alice    Miami    0.1
4  Lucas      NYC    0.0
```

```
def searchedValue(Name, Location):
    merged = df.merge(df2, on=["Name", "Location"])
    result = merged[(merged.Name == Name) & (merged.Location == Location)]
    if not result.size:
        return "No match found"
    return f"The Value is: {result['Value'].iloc[0]}"
print(searchedValue("Alice", "Paris"))
print(searchedValue("Alice", "Miami"))
print(searchedValue("Alice", "NOOOOOOOOO"))
```

```
The Value is: 0.4
The Value is: 0.1
No match found
```